# APP installation - iPhone

Tags: automation, ios, mdm

I am trying to automate the installing procedure of iPhone apps (i.e) installing apps for around 5000 phones. For this I am planning to deploy an MDM server in Windows Server 2008 containing Active Directory. Once the successful registration of handsets is established the complete control of iPhone can be taken by the admin. I have following doubts:

1) My main objective is to push the apps that are available in the app store, hence Apple Push Notification Certificate will be sufficient to set up my MDM server and install apps?

2) Once the user registers his iOS device will I be able to install/uninstall applications into the device?

3) Can I implement payload mechanisms like AppLock Payload by just having Apple Push Notification Certificate?

Comment: Without knowing what MDM product you're going with, how in the world are we supposed to be able to answer this question? Read the documentation and talk to your vendor.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't give u any specification. My objective is to install apps in the company owned devices just as a administrator. And I am planning to set up my own MDM server.

Comment: Which MDM server?

Comment: I am planning to get a Enterprise Developer Certificate from Apple and install my own MDM server.

Comment: This question is better suited to StackOverflow, because you're asking about features of a programming framework. That doesn't mean it's a bad question, it's simply better suited for the QA site devoted to programming rather than the one for systems administration - even though your end goal is managing these devices, you're writing your own software to get there.

Answer (score 1):

http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Deployment_Technical_Reference_EN_Feb14.pdf

Page 24 does seem to suggest that you will need a Push Notification Certificate to enable your custom MDM solution to communicate with the managed devices

Page 26 answers question 2.

> MDM servers can deploy both App Store apps and in-house enterprise
>   apps to  devices over the air. Both paid and free App Store apps can
>   be managed by an  MDM server using Volume Purchase Program (VPP)
>   managed distribution. See  “Volume Purchase Program” in Chapter 4 for
>   more information about managed  distribution with MDM.  Installing VPP
>   apps occurs in one of three ways. Users with a personal device are 
>   prompted by MDM to install the app from the App Store, and they are
>   required to  enter their Apple ID. With an institution-owned
>   supervised device that is enrolled  with MDM, app installation occurs
>   silently

Question 3, I don't entirely understand. You're really going to have to dig into Apple's documentation on MDM and reach out to them. You're paying for a service, they offer support and they also have a forum.